# В чём разница между color и background-color? Объясните, пожалуйста

Tags: html, css

1)Вот пример: в a.navig:after у меня применен background-color: red. a.navig:after отвечает за линию, которая будет появляться при наведении в  a.navig:hover:after. Не пойму, типа потому, что я линию создал, как блок, у неё есть бэкграунд (задал ширину, высоту...)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

div.cover {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url('../images/travel_bg.jpeg') center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}

div.container {
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

a.navig {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Baloo Tamma 2', cursive;
    margin: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.navig:hover {
    color: red;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

a.navig:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

a.navig:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&family=Baloo+Tamma+2&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Traveler</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='cover'>
        <div class='container'>
            <a class='navig' href='#'>Air tickets</a>
            <a class='navig' href='#'>R/w tickets</a>
            <a class='navig' href='#'>Hotels</a>
            <a class='navig' href='#'>Buses</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Также, объясните, если не трудно, почему в a.navig:after нужен display: block? Без него линия не отображается. Я предполагаю, что из-за того, что родитель(div.container) у a.navig:after  имеет display: inline-flex. Подскажите, прав или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала разберёмся конкретно по вопросу, который указан в заголовке: "В чём разница между `color` и `background-color`?"

Если в двух словах, то `color` используется для изменения цвета текста, а `background-color` для изменения цвета фона.

Пример:

```css
.color {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="color">Фон синий, а текст красный</span>
```

Подробнее о свойствах: **[background-color](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-color)** и **[color](http://htmlbook.ru/css/color)**

---

Далее разберём вопросы уже в описание.

> 1)Вот пример: в a.navig:after у меня применен background-color: red. a.navig:after отвечает за линию, которая будет появляться при наведении в a.navig:hover:after. Не пойму, типа потому, что я линию создал, как блок, у неё есть бэкграунд (задал ширину, высоту...)

Не понял о чём вопрос..

---

> Также, объясните, если не трудно, почему в a.navig:after нужен display: block? Без него линия не отображается. Я предполагаю, что из-за того, что родитель(div.container) у a.navig:after имеет display: inline-flex. Подскажите, прав или нет?

Скорее всего это связанно с спецификой псевдоэлементов

> Для `::after` характерны следующие особенности.
>
> 1. При добавлении `::after` к блочному элементу, значение свойства `display` может быть только: `block`, `inline`, `none`, `marker`. Все остальные значения будут трактоваться как `block`.
> 2. При добавлении `::after` к встроенному элементу, `display` ограничен значениями `inline` и `none`. Все остальные будут восприниматься как `inline`.
>
> Вырезка с [Псевдоэлемент ::after | htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/css3/after)

Answer (score 0):

- псевдоэлементы `:before` и `:after` по дефолту инлайновые (имеют `dispaly: inline`).
- `background-color` - устанавливает фоновый цвет для блока, `color` - цвет самого текста. но я думаю, что Вы не это хотели спросить, верно?

Comment: Ну, немного не то

Comment: @Lirika, окэ. переформулируйте Ваш вопрос